# Disable swipe to view sidemenu when using tabs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm writing a small ionic app and have an issue. I'm using a sidemenu and also tabs. I have an ionic slide-box in one of my views, when I wipe this slidebox from left to right the side menu slides out. I've read through various related topics on the ionic forum but none have worked.

I've tried adding `drag-content="false"` to various tags and also added `$ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);` to my controller.

Neither worked. I think it's because I'm using a sidemenu, with tabs and views in the tabs. Heres my code:

index.html

```
    <ion-side-menus>

    <!-- Header bar -->
    <ion-side-menu-content ng-controller="NavCtrl" drag-content="false">
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
            <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-ios7-arrow-back">
            </ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-bar>

        <!-- Page content -->
        <ion-nav-view drag-content="false" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content> 

    <!-- Side menu -->
    <ion-side-menu side="left" class="side-menu">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-dark">
            <h1 class="title">Menu</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content has-header="true">

            <div ng-if="authData.twitter" class="logged-in-user item item-avatar">
                <img ng-src="{{authData.twitter.cachedUserProfile.profile_image_url}}"/>
                <h2>Hello, {{authData.twitter.displayName}}</h2>
                <p>Logged in via Twitter</p>
            </div>

            <div ng-if="authData.facebook" class="logged-in-user item item-avatar">
                <img ng-src="{{authData.facebook.cachedUserProfile.picture.data.url}}"/>
                <h2>Hello, {{authData.facebook.displayName}}</h2>
                <p>Logged in via Facebook</p>
            </div>

            <ul class="list">
                <li>
                    <a class="item item-icon-left" menu-close nav-clear href="#/venue">
                        <i class="icon ion-ios7-location"></i>Venue
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="item item-icon-left" menu-close nav-clear href="#/lunch">
                        <i class="icon ion-pizza"></i>Lunch
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="item item-icon-left" menu-close nav-clear href="#/wifi">
                        <i class="icon ion-wifi"></i>Wifi
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </ion-content>
        <ion-footer-bar class="bar bar-dark">
            <button class="button button-icon icon ion-log-out menu-close nav-clear" ng-controller="LoginCtrl" ng-click="logout()"> Logout</button>
        </ion-footer-bar>
    </ion-side-menu>  

  </ion-side-menus>
```

and my view:

```
<ion-view title="Agenda">
<ion-content drag-content="false">
    <ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)">
        <ion-slide>
            <div class="header-card header-card--image">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                        <h3 class="header-card__heading">Happening now</h3>
                        <img ng-src="img/me.jpeg" class="header-card__avatar"/>
                        <h2 class="header-card__heading">some guy</h2>
                        <p class="header-card__text">Some title</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
            <div class="header-card header-card--image">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                        <h3 class="header-card__heading">Coming Next</h3>
                        <img ng-src="img/me.jpeg" class="header-card__avatar"/>
                        <h2 class="header-card__heading">Some guy</h2>
                        <p class="header-card__text">Slowly taking over the world</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slide-box>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="(id,agendaItem) in agendaItems" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/agendaItem/{{agendaItem.$id}}" class="item item-avatar item-with-grid">
            <img ng-src="{{agendaItem.image}}">
            <p>{{agendaItem.startTime}} <i ng-if="agendaItem.hasNotificationSet == true" class="icon-left ion-ios7-bell"></i></p>
            <h2>{{agendaItem.title}}</h2>
            <p>{{agendaItem.speaker}}</p>
            <ion-option-button ng-class="agendaItem.hasNotificationSet ? 'button-balanced icon ion-ios7-bell' : 'button-positive icon ion-ios7-bell-outline'" ng-controller="NotificationCtrl" ng-click="add(agendaItem)"></ion-option-button>

            <!--<ion-option-button ng-click="getNotificationIds()"></ion-option-button>-->
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

and my controller:

```
.controller('AgendaCtrl', function($scope, AgendaFactory, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $rootScope, $ionicPopup, $timeout, $cordovaLocalNotification, NotificationFactory) {

    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false); // doesn't seem to work

    var agendaItems = AgendaFactory.getAgenda();

    // Loop through agenda itens and check which have notifications set
    agendaItems.$loaded().then(function(array) {
        angular.forEach(array, function(value, key) {

        if (NotificationFactory.isNotificationScheduled(value.notificationId) == true) {
                value.hasNotificationSet = true;
        } else {
                value.hasNotificationSet = false;
        }

    });

    $scope.getNotificationIds = function () {
        $cordovaLocalNotification.getScheduledIds().then(function (scheduledIds) {
          console.log(scheduledIds);
        });
      };

        $scope.agendaItems = agendaItems;
    });

    $scope.firstTimeLogin = $rootScope.firstTimeLogin;

})
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I'm using  something like this on my app:

```
.controller('AgendaCtrl', function($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate){
  $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(){
      $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);
    });
  $scope.$on('$ionicView.leave', function(){
      $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(true);
    });
})
```

now, when you leave the view it's draggable again.

Comment: Great! Worked on Ionic 1.0.0

Comment: Does it make range select slow to use for anyone else ?

Comment: I have done the same thing but I cant seem to hide my header menu button on the page where the side menu is disabled. The user can still tap the button to reveal the menu. Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you that works! couldn't get ( drag-content='false' ) to play nice.

Comment: same code i tried but i am getting back button and sidemenu button both on my header

Answer (score 8):

`ion-side-menu-content drag-content="false"` put this code in your `ion-sidemenu`'s `ion-pane` tag

Comment: put it in your ion-side-menus tag

Answer (score 2):

```
<ion-side-menus>
  <ion-side-menu-content drag-content="false">
  ............
  </ion-side-menu-content>
</ion-side-menus>
```

this is sample code follow @Chetan Buddh's answer