# Don't show side menu on drag ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a calendar element on my ionic app. When user swipe left or right on it,  it goes to a different month. One problem/challenge is that when I swipe to the right the side bar is showing.

I did use `drag-content="false"` and that disabled the swipe menu function everywhere but I want it only on that calendar element.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34757476/disable-side-menu-swipe-event-while-using-horizontal-slider-ionic) Stackoverflow post with a answer but I did not understand how it worked because I can't find any difference between the content elements. In that post they also included a codepen link to an answer [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/NewbieDev/pen/rxzxYL)

UPDATE:
[Here a link to the calendar plugin](https://github.com/Russian60/flex-calendar)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable swipe to view sidemenu when using tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29128758/disable-swipe-to-view-sidemenu-when-using-tabs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could bind `drag-content` directive to a scope variable (boolean) and then change its value when mouse is over the calendar component:

```
<ion-side-menu-content drag-content="drag">
```

So register the listeners for mouseover/mouseleave events on calendar:

```
<flex-calendar on-touch="mouseoverCalendar()" on-release="mouseleaveCalendar()" drag-content="toggledrag" options="options" events="events"></flex-calendar>
```

and insert in your controller:

```
  $scope.drag = true;

  $scope.mouseoverCalendar = function() {
    $scope.drag = false;
  };

  $scope.mouseleaveCalendar = function() {
    $scope.drag = true;
  };
```

Here is an example using [Flex Calendar](https://github.com/Russian60/flex-calendar): http://codepen.io/beaver71/pen/bEmaJZ

Comment: both functions are not going to be triggered

Comment: Which kind of calendar component are you using, please?

Comment: I added a link to the calendar plugin

Comment: Check the new CodePen: I've adapted the previous one using Flex Calendar

Comment: I fixed it with ng-touch and ng-release. This is because the MouseOverEvents can't being use on mobile applications because there is no mouse :)

Comment: You could post your own answer here on SO or edit my answer with your fix

Answer (score 0):

Put this into the controller of your calendar-view and it will the menu as you enter the calendar and re-enable it as you leave the view:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(){
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);
});
$scope.$on('$ionicView.leave', function(){
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(true);
});
```

Answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29128758/disable-swipe-to-view-sidemenu-when-using-tabs)

Comment: I only want it disabled in the <flex-calendar> element